# Django: How to test relation between models to grant access to views?

Tags: python, django

I have a `User` class in Django. A user can be linked (FK) to a `CliProfile` (client), a `BizProfile` (owner), both, or none of them.
I'd like to allow clients to access some views, and owners to access other views.

What is the right way to do it?

For now, I use Django [user_passes_test](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test:)

Here are the custom decorators I made:

```
def is_owner_check(self):
    try:
        self.bizprofile
        return True
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return False
    except AttributeError: # This error is raised by anonymous user trying to access view
        return False

def is_client_check(self):
    try:
        self.cliprofile
        return True
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        return False
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

This seems to work, but I was asking myself if there is a "cleaner" way that a try except block to test this? Plus, it's not really DRY. I just would like to know if what I did is the thing to do, or if not, how to do?

Thanks guys!

Comment: How about using: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization ?

Comment: Seemed overkill to me...